# .angular-cli.json - what $schema path to use for globally installed cli?

Tags: angular

I'm implementing a custom .angular-cli.json for an ng4 app integrated into a .NET MVC app. A $schema property value is required. I had previously installed the CLI globally but I wasn't sure how the $schema path should be defined so I also installed the CLI into the parent project of the integrated ng4 app and updated the $schema path like this which doesn't return a schema validation error:

"$schema": "../node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",

When using the CLI for an ng2+ app, do I need to install the CLI locally for each ng2+ app?  Or is there a clean way to update the $schema property to point to a global cli install reference?

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem first and therefore I removed the `$schema` line. After I did all the upgrade steps to be able to use the project with Angular 10 properly, I put it back in like this:

```
"$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
```

So even if this file was initially NOT installed locally, it WAS at the end for me. The `..` was not okay, because then it pointed out of the project. Just `node_modules/...` does not work either, because it looks for the file somewhere else again. For me only `./` worked.

Comment: Please do any one know the local $schema path for tsconfig.json too?

Comment: I don't know about that one, sorry. I've got no schema-reference there.

Answer (score 0):

The only reason for `$schema` property in agnular cli json is to help your IDEA to find schema (possible properties) in your configuration
So if you will remove, nothing bad will happen

so, where can you find global ng cli schema
if you are using npm@5, just do `npm -h`

on mac you will see something like `npm@5.3.0 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm` in the last line, so
global schema will be in `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json`